# Can convolution in C++ faster than MATLAB conv2?

Tags: matlab, convolution

Recently I am working on accelerating convolution in mex. I use opencv filter 2d but it shows slow than MATLAB, and then I write my own convolution based on SSE and openmp, it seems that at the same machine, I can't faster than MATLAB. I cannot use FFT as my convolution kernel is 5*5, also I cannot separate the kernel because it's not regulated kernel, just random element in the kernel. Can I fast than that?

Actually, if I use better machine, e.g. The machine with more threads, I can achieve the same speed as MATLAB(conv2). I want to ask if I can achieve that speed with the normal machine I am available( I use machine with 2 kernel 8 threads now)` 
MATLAB Test Code:

```
 i_h = 2000;
 i_w = 1000;   
 a1 = ones(i_h,i_w);
 for k=1:2000
     for i=1:i_h
         for j=1:i_w
             a1(i,j)=2+rand();
         end
     end
     a1 = single(a1);
     b = ones(5,5);
     for i=1:5
         for j=1:5
             b(i,j)=3+rand();
         end
     end
     b = single(b);
     tic, 
     c = conv2(a1,b,'same');
     toc,

     tic,
     c1 = Verify_01_20160310(a1,b);
     toc,
     c3=c-c1;
     diff = max(abs(c3(:)));
     disp(diff);
 end
```

`
Mex Code:

```
    // SSE_Conv_Mex_01_20160310.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "SSE_1d_conv.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include "time.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "mex.h"
#include <ctime>

time_t t0,t1;


bool Conv2d_32f_SSE(float *psh_2D_source, const int i_W, const int i_H,
                    float *psh_2D_dest, float *piKernel25, float *pi_WorkingLines)
{
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        float *pshLine_in_prev2, *pshLine_in_prev1, *pshLine_in_curr, 
              *pshLine_in_next1, *pshLine_in_next2, *piLine_out;

        float *piLine_prev2, *piLine_prev1, *piLine_curr,
              *piLine_next1, *piLine_next2; 

        float *piLine_res_prev2, *piLine_res_prev1, *piLine_res_curr,
              *piLine_res_next1, *piLine_res_next2;


        int i,j,i_current_thread_num;


    #pragma omp for
        for(i=0; i<i_H; i++)
        {
            piLine_out = psh_2D_dest + i*i_W;


            i_current_thread_num = omp_get_thread_num();

            piLine_prev2 = pi_WorkingLines + i_current_thread_num*5*i_W;
            if(i>=2)
            {
                pshLine_in_prev2 = psh_2D_source + (i-2)*i_W;
                Conv1d_1line_SSE(pshLine_in_prev2, i_W, piKernel25+20, piLine_prev2);
            }
            else memset(piLine_prev2,0,i_W*sizeof(float));
            piLine_res_prev2 = piLine_prev2;

            piLine_prev1 = pi_WorkingLines + (i_current_thread_num*5+1)*i_W;
            if(i>=1)
            {
                pshLine_in_prev1 = psh_2D_source + (i-1)*i_W;
                Conv1d_1line_SSE(pshLine_in_prev1, i_W, piKernel25+15, piLine_prev1);
            }
            else memset(piLine_prev1,0,i_W*sizeof(float));
            piLine_res_prev1 = piLine_prev1;

            piLine_curr  = pi_WorkingLines + (i_current_thread_num*5+2)*i_W;
            pshLine_in_curr  = psh_2D_source + i*i_W;
            Conv1d_1line_SSE(pshLine_in_curr, i_W, piKernel25+10, piLine_curr);
            piLine_res_curr = piLine_curr;

            piLine_next2 = pi_WorkingLines + (i_current_thread_num*5+4)*i_W;
            if(i<i_H-2)
            {
                pshLine_in_next2 = psh_2D_source + (i+2)*i_W;
                Conv1d_1line_SSE(pshLine_in_next2, i_W, piKernel25, piLine_next2);

            }
            else memset(piLine_next2,0,i_W*sizeof(float));
            piLine_res_next2 = piLine_next2;

            piLine_next1 = pi_WorkingLines + (i_current_thread_num*5+3)*i_W; 
            if(i<i_H-1)
            {

                pshLine_in_next1 = psh_2D_source + (i+1)*i_W;
                Conv1d_1line_SSE(pshLine_in_next1, i_W, piKernel25+5, piLine_next1);
            }
            else  memset(piLine_next1,0,i_W*sizeof(float));
            piLine_res_next1 = piLine_next1;

            for(j=0; j<i_W; piLine_res_prev2 += 4, piLine_res_prev1 += 4,piLine_res_curr +=4, piLine_res_next1 +=4, piLine_res_next2 +=4, piLine_out +=4, j+=4)
            {
                _mm_stream_ps(piLine_out,_mm_add_ps(_mm_load_ps(piLine_res_next2),_mm_add_ps(_mm_load_ps(piLine_res_next1),
                             _mm_add_ps(_mm_load_ps(piLine_res_curr),_mm_add_ps(_mm_load_ps(piLine_res_prev1),
                                _mm_load_ps(piLine_res_prev2))))));
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}


bool Conv1d_1line_SSE(float *pshLine_in, const int i_W, float *piKernel5, float *piLine_out)
{
    __m128 mf_zero = _mm_setzero_ps();
    __m128 mf_f32,
           mf_Multd32_1_1, mf_Multd32_1_2,
           mf_Multd32_2_1, mf_Multd32_2_2,
           mf_Multd32_1_2_prev = mf_zero, mf_Multd32_1_1_prev = mf_zero,
           mf_Multd32_2_1_prev, mf_Multd32_2_2_prev,
           mf_sum;

    __m128 mf_KernLeft2  = _mm_set1_ps(piKernel5[4]),
           mf_KernLeft1  = _mm_set1_ps(piKernel5[3]),
           mf_KernCen    = _mm_set1_ps(piKernel5[2]),
           mf_KernRight1 = _mm_set1_ps(piKernel5[1]),
           mf_KernRight2 = _mm_set1_ps(piKernel5[0]);

    int i;
    // if the variable has two 1 or 2, then the first 1 or 2 represent the Kernel before center or after center, the second 1 or 2 represent the distance between the kernel and the center kernel
    mf_f32 = _mm_load_ps(pshLine_in);

    mf_Multd32_1_2 = _mm_mul_ps(mf_f32, mf_KernLeft2);
    mf_Multd32_1_1 = _mm_mul_ps(mf_f32, mf_KernLeft1);

    mf_sum = _mm_add_ps(*(__m128*)&_mm_alignr_epi8(*(__m128i*)(&mf_Multd32_1_2), *(__m128i*)(&mf_Multd32_1_2_prev), 2*sizeof(float)), _mm_mul_ps(mf_f32, mf_KernCen));
    mf_sum = _mm_add_ps(*(__m128*)&_mm_alignr_epi8(*(__m128i*)(&mf_Multd32_1_1), *(__m128i*)(&mf_Multd32_1_1_prev), 3*sizeof(float)), mf_sum);

    mf_Multd32_1_1_prev = mf_Multd32_1_1;
    mf_Multd32_1_2_prev = mf_Multd32_1_2;

    mf_Multd32_2_2 = _mm_mul_ps(mf_f32, mf_KernRight2);
    mf_Multd32_2_1 = _mm_mul_ps(mf_f32, mf_KernRight1);

    mf_Multd32_2_2_prev = mf_Multd32_2_2;
    mf_Multd32_2_1_prev = mf_Multd32_2_1;

    for(i=4; i<i_W; i+=4)
    {
        mf_f32 = _mm_load_ps(pshLine_in+i);

        mf_Multd32_2_1 = _mm_mul_ps(mf_f32, mf_KernRight1);
        mf_Multd32_2_2 = _mm_mul_ps(mf_f32, mf_KernRight2);


        mf_sum = _mm_add_ps(*(__m128*)&_mm_alignr_epi8(*(__m128i*)&mf_Multd32_2_1, *(__m128i*)&mf_Multd32_2_1_prev, 1*sizeof(float)), mf_sum);
        mf_sum = _mm_add_ps(*(__m128*)&_mm_alignr_epi8(*(__m128i*)&mf_Multd32_2_2, *(__m128i*)&mf_Multd32_2_2_prev, 2*sizeof(float)), mf_sum);

        mf_Multd32_2_2_prev = mf_Multd32_2_2;
        mf_Multd32_2_1_prev = mf_Multd32_2_1;

        _mm_store_ps(piLine_out+i-4, mf_sum);

        mf_Multd32_1_1 = _mm_mul_ps(mf_f32, mf_KernLeft1); 
        mf_Multd32_1_2 = _mm_mul_ps(mf_f32, mf_KernLeft2);

        mf_sum = _mm_add_ps(*(__m128*)&_mm_alignr_epi8(*(__m128i*)&mf_Multd32_1_2, *(__m128i*)&mf_Multd32_1_2_prev, 2*sizeof(float)), _mm_mul_ps(mf_f32, mf_KernCen));
        mf_sum = _mm_add_ps(*(__m128*)&_mm_alignr_epi8(*(__m128i*)&mf_Multd32_1_1, *(__m128i*)&mf_Multd32_1_1_prev, 3*sizeof(float)), mf_sum);

        mf_Multd32_1_1_prev = mf_Multd32_1_1;
        mf_Multd32_1_2_prev = mf_Multd32_1_2;
    }
    mf_sum = _mm_add_ps(*(__m128*)&_mm_alignr_epi8(*(__m128i*)&mf_zero, *(__m128i*)&mf_Multd32_2_1, 1*sizeof(float)), mf_sum);
    mf_sum = _mm_add_ps(*(__m128*)&_mm_alignr_epi8(*(__m128i*)&mf_zero, *(__m128i*)&mf_Multd32_2_2, 2*sizeof(float)), mf_sum);

    _mm_store_ps(piLine_out+i-4, mf_sum);

    return true;
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
{

        int input1_row = (int)mxGetM(prhs[0]);
        int input1_column = (int)mxGetN(prhs[0]); 

        float *input1;


        float *input2;

        const int size_out_arr[2]={input1_row,input1_column};

        plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(2,size_out_arr,mxSINGLE_CLASS,mxREAL);
        float *output; 

        int i_omp_max_threads = omp_get_max_threads();
        float *pi_WorkingLines =(float*)_mm_malloc(i_omp_max_threads*5*input1_row*sizeof(float), 32);


        input1 = (float*)mxGetData(prhs[0]);
        input2 = (float*)mxGetData(prhs[1]);
        output = (float*)mxGetData(plhs[0]);
        t0=clock();
        Conv2d_32f_SSE(input1,input1_row,input1_column,output,input2,pi_WorkingLines);
        t1=clock();
        mexPrintf("convol time: %d\n", t1-t0);
        _mm_free(pi_WorkingLines);        
}
```

Below is the code that I use conv2 almost 40*36 times, because P.nScales is 36, and opts.filters is any 5*5*40 three dimension filter, after the repmat, C becomes 548*966*40.
`

```
 for i=1:P.nScales, fs=opts.filters;
      C=repmat(P.data{i},[1 1 size(fs,4)]);           
      for j=1:size(C,3)
       C(:,:,j)=conv2(C(:,:,j),fs(:,:,j)); 
      end  
      P.data{i}=imResample(C,.5); 
  end

end
```

`
Because of the convolution use 128 bits register and the data type is float, so it can take care of 4 float numbers one time. That means, you should set the height as the integer times of 4(because MATLAB store data with row first, so the convolution in mex first deal with its row).

Comment: What is your intention in reimplementing conv2?

Comment: @Daniel I need to achieve real-time, but the source image is 548*966*40 and the kernel is 5*5*40, and I have 36 array of images like this. Conv2 in MATLAB is really fast, but after almost 40*36 loop, it is far exceed the time required. So I am wandering if I can conv in C++ which is fast dealing with loops. The parfor in MATLAB is the multithreaded way, but there exist communication problem, meaning that I need to copy the data into each thread and do the conv, which cannot accelerate but slow.

Comment: Okay, now I get it. Beating a single call of `conv2` is something you would never manage to do but that might be possible. Please put the MATLAB code demonstrating what you want  to do into your question.

Comment: @Daniel I'll put it tomorrow morning as it is 2:09am now and I cannot get access to my lab computer

Comment: Consider using `imfilter` instead of `conv2` if you have the image processing toolbox.  `imfilter` takes advantage of the Intel Integrated Performance Primitives (IIPP) which is very fast on CPU.  I highly doubt that your naive implementation will be faster than `conv2` in MATLAB.

Comment: You could also try [FFT-based convolution](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24504-fft-based-convolution).

Comment: @rayryeng thank you, I'll try imfilter.that's true, but not always the truth. When the data is small, the convolution in c++ cannot match the MATLAB, but when the data is big, especially when it is more than 200*200 image, I can match the same speed as MATLAB.

Comment: @horchler thank you, but I think that my task is not suitable for FFT?

Comment: @JinghengLuo I can't say whether your statement is true or false unless I see some code.

Comment: @rayryeng Sorry, I'll put it now

Comment: @Daniel I have already put the code

Comment: @rayryeng I think you are right, my argument before was wrong. My code is used to deal with float type, when the number exceeds the limit of float, it just use the limit as the answer, and in that case, it shows fast. You are right, I use almost double time to convolution each image.

Comment: @JinghengLuo: Did you try out the `conv2fft` code I linked to? I'm curious why you say you think your task is not suitable?

Comment: @rayryeng as the link mentioned, when the kernel length na and nb > 20, the convfft is faster than conv2, but my kernel is 5*5. After finishing the whole convolution, conv2 uses 0.97s while my own mex file using sse + openmp can reach the 0.73s

Comment: Using SSE and OpenMP may provide speedups. I actually didn't know you were doing that.  Have you tried increasing the kernel size?  Do you get the same speedups?  In any case, I think your post is unsuitable for StackOverflow.  You should probably post on Code Review instead.  Your code works, but you'd like feedback and recommendations on how to possibly make it faster.

Comment: @rayryeng thank you so much! I'm a new in programming and don't know where to find solution. I usually find answers in stack overflow.

Comment: @rayryeng I cannot enlarge the kernel it should be 5*5